Backswipe with Capacitor 6
Following this tutorial around january of 2024 with Capacitorjs version 5 helped me to add navigating back using backswipe on ios devices.
However now, using Capacitor 6, I'm no longer able to make it work.
I looked up Capacitor's custom plugin docs, to see if anything changed.
I followed their steps, creating group called plugins, under it group Backswipe.
Backswipe group contains 3 files, but when I run the code, backswipe to navigate doesn't work.
What else could I do?
// App/App/plugins/Backswipe/BackswipePlugin.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Capacitor/Capacitor.h>

CAP_PLUGIN(BackswipePlugin, "BackswipePlugin",)

// App/App/plugins/Backswipe/BackswipePlugin.swift

import Foundation
import Capacitor

@objc(BackswipePlugin)
public class BackswipePlugin: CAPPlugin {
   
    override public func load() {
        bridge?.webView?.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true;
    }
}

// App/App/plugins/Backswipe/App Name-Bridging-Header.h

//

I also tried renaming BackswipePlugin.m to Backswipe.m, didn't help.
My other guess is if the space in autogenerated bridging header could be causing the problems.
Any help is welcome, thank you.

I was able to get a solution working for Capacitor 6 by following the steps listed here: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/ios/custom-code

Create a file under App/plugins/SwipeGesture called SwipeGesturePlugin.swift by adding the file via xcode.

// SwipeGesturePlugin.swift
import Foundation
import Capacitor

@objc(SwipeGesturePlugin)
public class SwipeGesturePlugin: CAPPlugin, CAPBridgedPlugin {
    public let identifier = "SwipeGesturePlugin"
    public let jsName = "SwipeGesture"
    public let pluginMethods: [CAPPluginMethod] = []

    override public func load() {
        if let webView = bridge?.webView as? WKWebView {
            webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        }
    }
}


Now we need to add a view controller file to the xcode project.


Right click on your App project folder, click "New File..."
Select "Cocoa Touch Class" then click "Next"
Name the file whatever you want, I named it PluginViewController
Change Subclass of to "UIViewController"
Change Language to Swift and next until the file is created
Replace the file contents with the following:

// PluginViewController.swift
import UIKit
import Capacitor

class PluginViewController: CAPBridgeViewController {
    override open func capacitorDidLoad() {
        bridge?.registerPluginInstance(SwipeGesturePlugin())
    }
}



Now we need to change the Main.storyboard to reference our new PluginViewController based on this documentation: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/ios/viewcontroller#edit-mainstoryboard


Double click on Main.storyboard
Expand "Plugin View Controller Scene"
Click on Bridge View Controller
In your menu bar click View > Inspectors > Identity (⌥ ⌘ 4)
Change the class to PluginViewController


If you have any .m files from your previous version of the plugin, that can safely be deleted.

